# Unfulfilled answers (this will be fixed in 'x' release - but it wasn't)

Tags: discussion

I'm curious, how should an asker go about finding an answer to a question if that question has been asked but the previous accepted answer does not work?

Specific example: [Applying discount brings grand total to negative 1 cent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12975/applying-discount-brings-grand-total-to-negative-1-cent) is fairly marked as a duplicate of [How do you fix rounding issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/how-do-you-fix-rounding-issues) but the answer to that question rather explicitly states that the issue will be fixed in 1.8.  The problem is, when I posted my question I identified that the problem I have still exists in 1.8

I'm not saying my question should be re-opened.  What I am trying to discern is whether or not there is a way to say "Hey, this answer turned out to be wrong...what now?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your situation is fairly unique. I would suggest posting a comment to the answer stating that issue still persists in 1.8.

Also if you are as grumpy as I am you can down-vote the answer.

Comment: Not feeling exceptionally grumpy today...maybe Monday :P

Answer (score 0):

As a general conventions:
In these cases I think the OP should state in the question. "*I tried the answers on (insert question link here) but the result is (insert result here)*".

I think that providing the result you get instead of saying "*but it doesn't work*" should get you a higher chance of your question not being marked as duplicate.

Comment: I'm actually ok with it being marked as a duplicate, because it obviously is...Having said that, I did provide my result in my question.

Comment: @DavidWilkins. Yeah I saw that. Nice work. I was talking about the general case. Just in case someone has a similar issue as yours (as concept) and decides to post a new question.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks :)